# Why innerHTML Is Not Working With JavaScript Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm implementing a loading placeholder or preloader on my website for that I have written a javascript code and it is working fine but the problem is when I put the preloader HTML code on index file it works, but when I store the same placeholader code on a JS variable using innerHTML it's not working.

Please check my below code and help me to debug the code.

```js
let preloader = document.querySelector('.homepage-loader');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

body.setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden; position: fixed;");

hidePreloader = () => {
    preloader.style.display = 'none';
}

scrollBody = () => {
   body.setAttribute("style", "overflow: ; position: ;");
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {    
   hidePreloader();
   scrollBody();    
});

document.querySelector('.preloader').innerHTML = 

`
<div class="homepage-loader">

   <h1>Please Wait... Content Is Loading</h1>

</div>

`;
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
.content {
    width:100vw;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="preloader">

</div>

<div class="content">
  <div>
      <h1>Content Here</h1>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script runs before the DOM is complete. The element doesn't exist yet at that time. Put the initialization into an event handler for the `DOMContentLoaded` event on `document`.

Comment: `TypeError: preloader is null"` ... did you not notice this error?

Comment: either use the `eventListener`: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // your fucntion })` or add the `defer` attribute to the script tag: `<script src="#" defer></script>`

Comment: PS `body.setAttribute("style", "overflow: ; position: ;");` is invalid as it misses a value. Besides of that it is the wrong way to add styles using `setAttribute`. Either use `.style` or `.classList`